# Unable to get correct image path using Sass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am studying Sass. And I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz3kElLbEHE) on youtube. Everything looks find but when it comes to calling the image I can't access my image inside images folder.

Here's my scss part:

```
img[alt="Programming Frameworks"] {
    content: image-url('small2.png');
}
```

And my config:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

And when I inspect the css from developer console I got this:

```
img[alt="Programming Frameworks"] {
    content: url('/images/small2.png?1479092109');
}
```

And when I manually modify the css output in dev console to this:

```
 img[alt="Programming Frameworks"] {
        content: url('../images/small2.png?1479092109');
 }
```

It can access the image but in my HTML. It doesn't show.

Can you help me? I new in sass development.

Here's my directory structure:

[image]

I also try this following code:

```
img[alt="Programming Frameworks"] {
    content: image-url('small3.png');
    width: image-width('../images/small3.png');
    height: image-height('../images/small3.png');
}
```

And I check my developer console and I got this:

```
img[alt="Programming Frameworks"] {
    content: url('/images/small3.png?1479092299');
    width: 466px;
    height: 308px;
}
```

The exact width and height is correct. But cant access the image. :(

Comment: Can you show your file directory structure?

Comment: Ok wait I will update my code

Comment: @BlackEnigma, I already updated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `config.rb` file

You need to add this line to it

`relative_assets = true`

This will allow compass helpers enable relative paths to images and other assets

Comment: Still no images. I also modified this line `http_path = "../"` but still no image

Comment: Change the http_path to what it was before `http_path = '/'`

Comment: Ok ill give it a try :)

Comment: Still no image. :(

Comment: Im thinking maybe there's a problem with my ruby version. I just saw that there are some post about the incompatibility issue with the ruby version together with the sass version.

Comment: What versions of `ruby`, `sass and `compass` are you using? I saw an [article](https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/989) that might help. You are using `compass watch` to check your files for changes right?

Comment: Yes I am using compass, wait ill check your post. :)

Comment: Here's my ruby version `2.5.1` and here's mys sass `Sass 3.4.22 (Selective Steve)`

Comment: When you add the `relative_assets = true` to `config.rb`, you need to stop `compass watch` then restart it. That should probably get it to work

Answer (score 0):

pls try give him height and width because ur path right so try to give height and width

Comment: Thanks but I already set the height and width. Check my last code. I set the width to `width: image-width('../images/small3.png')` in what I have heared in the tutorial it will get the exact width of the image. Do I need to setup the height and width manually like hardcoded?

Comment: add http_path = "../"

Comment: same effect, no images